# Почему не работает transform: translate по оси z?

Tags: html, css, transform

У меня есть элемент, которому заданы `transform: perspective(500px)` и `transform: translate(0 0 100px)`. Почему элемент не двигается по оси зет?

Кроме того, при добавлении `transform: translate` перестает работать `rotate`. Что я делаю не так? Большое спасибо.

Мои примеры - 1. Без добавления `transform: translate`

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(50deg);
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

2. С добавлением `transform: translate`

   ```css
   .block {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     background: pink;
     transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(50deg) translate(0 0 100px);
     outline: 1px solid black;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="block"></div>
   ```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут дело было в том, что само свойство `transform: translate` может задавать значение ТОЛЬКО для x, y. Что же касается оси z, то тут нужно отдельно прописывать `translateZ` и задавать ему значение.

!!!Также значения в `transform: translate` должны быть разделены запятой – `transform: translate(100px, 200px)` В противном случае свойство не будет работать.

Comment: есть еще [`translate3d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d) если все три координаты нужны

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте использовать `translateX`/`translateY`/`translateZ`:

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(50deg) translateZ(100px);
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```